# After multiplying array to a row of matrix only one element is correct

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, multidimensional-array

i was trying to write Gaussian elimination method on C

> Code:

```
float M[4][5] = 
    {
        {99.69, 7.07, 53, -4, 155.76},
        {-138.41, 14.11, -6.31, 5.6, -124.74},
        {55, 35.174, 685, 1.4, 776.574},
        {33, 21, -3.28, -0.28, 50.44}
    };


   float t_arr[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};

    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {   
            t_arr[j] = M[2][j];
            t_arr[j] *= (-(M[3][0]/M[2][0]));
            printf("t_arr[%d] = %f\n",j, t_arr[j]);
            M[3][j] += t_arr[j]; 
        }
```

Error appears here:

```
t_arr[j] *= (-(M[3][0]/M[2][0]));
```

As i wanted it to be is that third row of matrix `M[2][j] == t_arr[j]`
That works, but after multiplying values of `t_arr[j] to (-(M[3][j]/M[2][0]))

> F.e `t_arr[0] * (-(M[3][0]/M[2][0]))` ==>> 55 * -33\55 = -33

It
Outputs:

```
t_arr[0] = -33.000000
t_arr[1] = -0.000000
t_arr[2] = -0.000000
t_arr[3] = -0.000000
t_arr[4] = -0.000000
```

Comment: What *should* it "output"?

Comment: it should output `t_arr[0] = -33.000000
t_arr[1] = -21.104401
t_arr[2] = -411.000031
t_arr[3] = -0.840000
t_arr[4] = -465.944397`

Comment: Tip: When investigating such issues, use `"%.17g"` as it is more informative: `printf("t_arr[%d] = %g\n",j, t_arr[j]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M[3][j] += t_arr[j];` in the first iteration will turn the value of `M[3][0]` to zero because the initial value of `M[3][0]` is `33` and the calculated value of `t_arr[0]` is `-33.000000`.

If you want to use the initial value of `M[3][0]` and `M[2][0]` in all iterations, you should do the calculation of `-(M[3][0]/M[2][0])` and save the result *before* the loop.

```c
float M[4][5] = 
    {
        {99.69, 7.07, 53, -4, 155.76},
        {-138.41, 14.11, -6.31, 5.6, -124.74},
        {55, 35.174, 685, 1.4, 776.574},
        {33, 21, -3.28, -0.28, 50.44}
    };


float t_arr[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};
float multiplier = (-(M[3][0]/M[2][0]);

for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        t_arr[j] = M[2][j];
        t_arr[j] *= multiplier;
        printf("t_arr[%d] = %f\n",j, t_arr[j]);
        M[3][j] += t_arr[j]; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, haven't thought about that

Answer (score 1):

After this statement in the first iteration of the loop

```
M[3][j] += t_arr[j];
```

the value of `M[3][0]` is equal to `0` ( `33.0 + -33.0` ).

So this expression  `(-(M[3][0]/M[2][0]))` will always evaluate to 0 in subsequent iterations of the loop.